# A continuous function on $[0,1]$ orthogonal to each monomial of the form $x^{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, orthogonal-polynomials, weierstrass-approximation

Let us consider the continuous functions over $[0,1]$ fulfilling
$$ \int_{0}^{1} f(x) x^n\,dx = 0 $$
for $n=0$ and for every $n\in E\subseteq\mathbb{N}^+$. The [Müntz–Szász theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCntz%E2%80%93Sz%C3%A1sz_theorem) gives that
$$ \sum_{n\in E}\frac{1}{n} = +\infty \Longleftrightarrow f(x)\equiv 0 $$
so there is a non-zero continuous function $f(x)$ such that
$$ \int_{0}^{1} f(x) x^{n^2}\,dx = 0 \tag{1}$$
holds for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

> **Question**: can we construct a nice, explicit function $f\neq 0$ fulfilling $(1)$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

We may consider functions of the form
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0} c_n P_n(2x-1) $$
with $P_n(2x-1)$ being the $n$-th shifted Legendre polynomial.
 The orthogonality to $1$ and $x$ translates into $c_0=c_1=0$, the orthogonality to $x^4$ translates into $\frac{2}{35}c_2+\frac{1}{70}c_3+\frac{1}{630}c_4=0$, the orthogonality to $x^9$ translates into $\frac{3}{55}c_2+\frac{21}{715}c_3+ \frac{9}{715}c_4 +\frac{3}{715}c_5+\frac{3}{2860}c_6+\frac{9}{48620}c_7+\frac{1}{48620}c_8+\frac{1}{923780}c_9=0$ and so on. The minimal (with respect to the $\ell^2$ norm) solution of this infinite system with $c_2=1$ (or $c_4=1$) *should* give a sequence $\{c_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ ensuring the continuity of $f(x)$, but this is non-trivial and I would appreciate a more explicit construction / example of such $f$.

**Addendum**: another possible construction is to apply the Gram-Schmidt process to $\{1,x,x^4,x^9,\ldots\}$ in order to get a sequence of polynomials $\{p_n(x)\}_{n\geq 0}$ such that

- $p_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} c_k x^{k^2}$
- $n\neq m \Longrightarrow \langle p_n(x),p_m(x)\rangle = 0$
- $\max_{x\in [0,1]} |p_n(x)| = 1$ or $\langle p_n(x),p_n(x)\rangle = 1$

then take $f(x)$ as the pointwise limit of a convergent subsequence of $\{p_n(x)\}_{n\geq 0}$.
 Still, not really explicit.

A more promising approach is to consider some lacunary Fourier series, like
$$ g(\theta) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(n\theta)}{n^2} - \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(n^2\theta)}{n^4}, $$
which clearly fulfills $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}g(\theta)\cos(n^2\theta)\,d\theta = 0$, then turn such $g(\theta)$ into an $f(x)$ fulfilling $(1)$ via some slick substitution.

Yet another way is to consider the inverse Laplace transform of
$$ \frac{1}{s}\prod_{k=0}^{n}\frac{k^2+1-s}{k^2+1+s} $$
evaluated at $-\log x$. This gives a polynomial, bounded between $-1$ and $1$, which is orthogonal to $1,x,x^4,\ldots,x^{n^2}$. Is this sequence of polynomials (or a subsequence of this sequence) convergent to a continuous function? I do not know. If so,
$$ f(x)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin(\pi\sqrt{s-1})}{\sqrt{s-1}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{s+1}}{\sin(\pi\sqrt{s+1})}\cdot \frac{1}{s}\right)(-\log x)$$
is an explicit solution. Here it is a plot of the first polynomials produced by the last approach:

[image]

Comment: Did you read a proof of Müntz-Szasz ?  Is it done by some method other than constructing a function $f$?

Comment: The proof of Muntz-Szasz goes more or less like this: provided that $E$ is dense enough (in the sense $\sum_{e\in E}\frac{1}{e}=+\infty$), the fact that $\langle f,x^e \rangle = 0$ implies that $\langle f,x^n\rangle = 0$ also for $n\not\in E$. This is essentially done by interpolation. The other part (if $E$ is not dense enough there are non-zero solutions), however, is non-constructive.

Comment: I can guarantee that $\frac{c_n}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$ is square-summable, just because $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{c_n^2}{2n+1}=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)^2\,dx$ for any $f\in L^2(0,1)$.

Comment: I think any straightforward attempt with an orthonormal basis for $L^2[0,1]$ is going to create an infinite system similar to (or worse than) the Legendre polynomials in your example.

Comment: The M-S theorem does _not_ say that $f=0$ if and only if $\sum_{n\in S}\frac1n=\infty$.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Short Answer.** Expanding **@orangeskid**'s answer, let

$$ F(x) := \frac{1}{\Psi_{\infty}(0)^2} - x - \frac{1}{\Psi_{\infty}(0)} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k} \frac{2k^2 \operatorname{sinhc}(\pi\sqrt{k^2 + 3})}{(k^2 + 1)(k^2 + 2)} x^{k^2+2}, $$

where $\operatorname{sinhc}(x) = \frac{\sinh x}{x}$ and

$$ \Psi_{\infty}(0) = \frac{\operatorname{sinhc}(\pi\sqrt{p+1})}{\operatorname{sinhc}(\pi\sqrt{p})}. $$

Although the above series converges only for $x \in [0, 1)$, we can prove that $F$ extends to an absolutely continuous function on $[0, 1]$ by setting $F(1) = 0$ and satisfies

$$ \int_{0}^{1} F(x) x^{n^2} \, \mathrm{d}x = 0 $$

for any $ n = 1, 2, \ldots$ Below is the graph of $f(x)$ on $[0, 1]$:

[image: graph of F]

---

**Proof of the claim.**

**Step 1.** Consider a sequence $-\frac{1}{2} < \alpha_1 < \alpha_2 < \ldots$. Also, we define the function $f_n$ by

\begin{align*}
f_n(x)
&:= \frac{
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & x^{\alpha_1} & \cdots & x^{\alpha_n} \\
\langle 1, t^{\alpha_1} \rangle & \langle t^{\alpha_1}, t^{\alpha_1} \rangle & \cdots & \langle t^{\alpha_n}, t^{\alpha_1} \rangle \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\langle 1, t^{\alpha_n} \rangle & \langle t^{\alpha_1}, t^{\alpha_n} \rangle & \cdots & \langle t^{\alpha_n}, t^{\alpha_n} \rangle
\end{vmatrix}
}{
\begin{vmatrix}
\langle t^{\alpha_1}, t^{\alpha_1} \rangle & \cdots & \langle t^{\alpha_n}, t^{\alpha_1} \rangle \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\langle t^{\alpha_1}, t^{\alpha_n} \rangle & \cdots & \langle t^{\alpha_n}, t^{\alpha_n} \rangle
\end{vmatrix}
},
\end{align*}

where $\langle g(t), h(t) \rangle = \int_{0}^{1} g(t)h(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$ denotes the inner product on $L^2([0,1])$. Then, as explained in @orangeskid's answer, for $\alpha > -\frac{1}{2}$ with $\alpha \notin \{\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots\}$,

$$ x^{\alpha} = f_n + (x^{\alpha} - f_n) $$

is an orthogonal decomposition of $x^{\alpha}$, where $x^{\alpha} - f_n \in V_n := \operatorname{span}(x^{\alpha_1}, \ldots, x^{\alpha_n})$ and $f_n \perp V_n$. Since $V_n$ is increasing in $n$, this implies that $f_n$ converges in $L^2([0,1])$. Moreover,

$$ \|f_n\|^2
= \operatorname{dist}(t^{\alpha}, V_n)^2
= \frac{G(t^{\alpha}, t^{\alpha_1}, \ldots, t^{\alpha_n})}{G(t^{\alpha_1}, \ldots, t^{\alpha_n})}, $$

where $G(v_1, \ldots, v_n) = \det[\langle v_i, v_j \rangle]$ is the Gram determinant.

**Step 2.** We can expand the determinant in the numerator along the first row and compute the coefficients using [Cauchy determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix). After a bit of computations, it turns out that

\begin{align*}
f_n(x) = x^{\alpha} - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\psi_{n,k}(\alpha_k)}{\psi_{n,k}(\alpha)} x^{\alpha_k},
\end{align*}

where $\phi_{n,k}(\alpha)$ is the rational function in $\alpha$ given by

$$ \psi_{n,k}(\alpha)
:= (\alpha_k - \alpha) \Psi_n(\alpha)
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\Psi_n(\alpha)
:= \frac{\prod_{j=1}^{n} (\alpha_j + \alpha + 1)}{\prod_{j=1}^{n} (\alpha_j - \alpha)}. $$

A similar computation also shows that

$$ \| f_n \|^2
= \frac{\prod_{j=1}^{n} (\alpha - \alpha_j)^2}{(2\alpha+1)\prod_{j=1}^{n} (\alpha + \alpha_j + 1)^2}
= \frac{1}{(2\alpha+1)\Phi_n(\alpha)^2}. $$

**Step 3.** Now let us specialize to the case where $(\alpha_k)$ is of the form $\alpha_k = k^2 + p$. Then Euler's reflection formula for the gamma function and Stirling's approximation show that

\begin{align*}
\prod_{j=1}^{n} (j^2 - q)
= \frac{(n-\sqrt{q})!(n+\sqrt{q})!}{(-\sqrt{q})!\sqrt{q}!}
= (n!)^2 \operatorname{sinc} (\pi \sqrt{q}) \prod_{j=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{j^2}{j^2 - q},
\end{align*}

where $\operatorname{sinc}(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$ is the (unnormalized) sinc function and $s! = \Gamma(s+1)$. Plugging this to $\Phi_n(\alpha)$, we get

\begin{align*}
\Psi_{n}(\alpha)
&= \frac{\operatorname{sinhc}(\pi\sqrt{p+\alpha+1})}{\operatorname{sinc}(\pi\sqrt{\alpha - p})}
\prod_{j=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{j^2 + p - \alpha}{j^2 + p + \alpha + 1}.
\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}
\psi_{n,k}(\alpha_k)
&= \lim_{s \to k} \left( k^2 - s^2 \right) \Psi_{n}(s^2 + p) \\
&= (-1)^{k-1} 2k^2 \operatorname{sinhc}(\pi\sqrt{\smash[b]{k^2 + 2p + 1}})
\prod_{j=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{j^2 - k^2}{j^2 + k^2 + 2p + 1}.
\end{align*}

Note that both $\Psi_n(\alpha)$ and $\psi_{n,k}(\alpha_k)$ converges as $n \to \infty$:

\begin{gather*}
\Psi_{\infty}(\alpha)
:= \lim_{n\to\infty} \Psi_{n}(\alpha)
= \frac{\operatorname{sinhc}(\pi\sqrt{p+\alpha+1})}{\operatorname{sinhc}(\pi\sqrt{p-\alpha})},
\\[0.5em]
\lim_{n\to\infty} \psi_{n,k}(\alpha_k)
= (-1)^{k-1} 2k^2 \operatorname{sinhc}(\pi\sqrt{\smash[b]{k^2 + 2p + 1}}).
\end{gather*}

Moreover, it is clear from the formula above that

$$ |\psi_{n,k}(\alpha_k)| \leq \frac{2k^2}{\pi\sqrt{k^2 + 2p + 1}} e^{\pi\sqrt{k^2 + 2p + 1}}$$

for all $1 \leq k \leq n$. Therefore, by the dominated convergence theorem, for each $x \in [0, 1)$,

\begin{align*}
f(x)
&:= \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) \\
&= x^{\alpha} - \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\Psi_n(\alpha)} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\psi_{n,k}(\alpha_k)}{k^2 + p - \alpha} x^{k^2 + p} \\
&= \bbox[color:navy;border:1px dotted navy;padding:3px]{x^{\alpha} + \frac{1}{\Psi_{\infty}(\alpha)} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k} \frac{2k^2}{k^2 + p - \alpha}  \operatorname{sinhc}(\pi\sqrt{\smash[b]{k^2 + 2p + 1}}) x^{k^2+p}.}
\end{align*}

Of course, this $f(x)$ must coincide with the $L^2$-limit of $f_n$. Therefore, for each $n = 1, 2, \ldots,$

$$ \int_{0}^{1} f(x)x^{n^2+p} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f_N(x)x^{n^2+p} \, \mathrm{d}x
= 0. $$

Below is the graph of $f(x)$ for $x \in [0, 1)$ when $\alpha = 0$ and $p = 1$.

[image: graph of f when a = 0 and p = 1]

**Step 4.** The function $f$ is almost good, but the issue is that $f$ seems suffering from the discontinuity at $x = 1$. To make amend of this, we now fix $\alpha = 0$, so that the corresponding $f$ is given by

$$ f(x)
= 1 + \frac{1}{\Psi_{\infty}(0)} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k} \frac{2k^2}{k^2 + p}  \operatorname{sinhc}(\pi\sqrt{\smash[b]{k^2 + 2p + 1}}) x^{k^2+p}. $$

Then

$$ \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
= \langle f, 1 \rangle
= \| f \|^2 + \underbrace{\langle f, 1-f \rangle}_{=0}
= \frac{1}{\Psi_{\infty}(0)^2}. $$

Using this, we define $F : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ as

\begin{align*}
F(x)
&= \int_{x}^{1} f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x - \int_{0}^{x} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \bbox[color:navy;border:1px dotted navy;padding:3px]{\frac{1}{\Psi_{\infty}(0)^2} - x - \frac{1}{\Psi_{\infty}(0)} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k} \frac{2k^2 \operatorname{sinhc}(\pi\sqrt{\smash[b]{k^2 + 2p + 1}})}{(k^2 + p)(k^2 + p + 1)} x^{k^2+p + 1}.}
\end{align*}

Then $F$ is absolutely continuous on all of $[0, 1]$. Also, performing integration by parts,

\begin{align*}
0
= \int_{0}^{1} f(x)x^{n^2+p} \, \mathrm{d}x
&= [ -F(x)x^{n^2+p} ]_{0}^{1} + (n^2 + p - 1)\int_{0}^{1} F(x) x^{n^2+p-1} \, \mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

and hence

$$ \int_{0}^{1} F(x) x^{n^2+p-1} \, \mathrm{d}x = 0, \qquad n = 1, 2, \ldots $$

So by choosing $p = 1$, the main claim follows.

Comment: This is very nice indeed!

Comment: (+1) Beautiful! Nice to know that I went close enough with the product I considered in the last part of the *Addendum*.

Comment: Just a minor nitpick: we do not have continuity at $1$, right? If existing, $\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)$ would be equal to $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{1}(n+1)x^n f(x)\,dx$. The sequence $\int_{0}^{1}(n+1) x^n f(x)\,dx$ has a zero subsequence, but from the graph $f(x)$ seems to be negative in a left neighbourhood of $1$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, Indeed, I also think it doesn't have continuity at $1$. Nice observation with supporting argument!

Answer (score 13):

HINT:

We can write the perpendicular vector drawn from $v$ to the subspace spanned by the linearly independent vectors $v_1$, $\ldots$, $v_n$ as

$$\frac{D}{ G(v_1, \ldots, v_n)}$$
where $G(v_i)$ is the Gram determinant of the system $v_i$, while
$$D = \left | \begin{matrix} v&v_1& \ldots & v_n \\ \langle v, v_1\rangle  & \langle v_1, v_1 \rangle & \ldots & \langle v_n, v_1 \rangle\\ \ldots & & \ldots \\ \langle v, v_n\rangle & \langle v_1, v_n \rangle & \ldots & \langle v_n, v_n \rangle \end{matrix} \right|$$

Indeed, it is easy to see that $\langle D, v_i\rangle = 0$ for all $i$, and the coefficient of $v$ in $D$ equals $G(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$

Note also that
$$d(v, (v_1, \ldots, v_n))^2 = \frac{G(v, v_1, \ldots, v_n)}{G(v_1, \ldots, v_n)}$$

Now consider in $L^{2}[0,1]$ the vectors $v_i$ being the function $x\mapsto x^{\alpha_i}$, while $v$ is the function $x\mapsto x^{\alpha}$. We get to calculate some minors that turn out to be Cauchy determinants. Moreover, if $\sum\frac{1}{\alpha_i} < \infty$, and $\alpha \not \in \{\alpha_i\}_i$, then
$$d^2(x^{\alpha}, (x^{\alpha_i})_i) >0$$
being expressed as an (infinite) convergent product. We also get the perpendicular from $x^{\alpha}$ to $(x^{\alpha_i})_i$ as a limit of a  sequence convergent in $L^2[0,1]$.

$\bf{Added:}$ It's worth writing down the formulas for the projection of a vector $v$ onto the span of linearly independent $v_1$, $\ldots$, $v_n$

$$\pi_{\langle v_1, \ldots, v_n\rangle}(v) = \sum_{i=1}^n  \frac{ G( (v_1, \ldots, \overset{i}{v},
\ldots, v_n), (v_1, \ldots, v_n)) }{G((v_1, \ldots, v_n), (v_1, \ldots, v_n))}\cdot v_i $$

where by $G(u, v)$ we denot the (determinant of ) a matrix with entries $\langle u_k, v_l\rangle $.

Now, the Gram determinant $G((x^{\alpha_i}), (x^{\beta_j}))$ is the [Cauchy determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix#Cauchy_determinants)
$$C((\alpha_i), (\beta_j))\colon = \left|\frac{1}{\alpha_i + \beta_j+1}\right|$$ which equals
$$V(\alpha_i ) \cdot V(\beta_i) \cdot \prod_{i,j} \frac{1}{\alpha_i + \beta_j + 1}$$
where $V$ are the [Vandermonde determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix).  We get the projection of the function $x^{\alpha}$ onto the span of $x^{\alpha_i}$

$$\sum_{i} \prod_{j, j\ne i} \frac{\alpha_j - \alpha}{\alpha_j - \alpha_i} \cdot \prod_j\frac{\alpha_j + \alpha_i + 1}{\alpha_j + \alpha+ 1} \cdot x^{\alpha_i}$$

Let's assume that $\alpha_j \ne 0$ for all $j$. We get the expression

$$\sum_i \frac{\prod_{j, j\ne i} (1- \frac{\alpha}{\alpha_j})}{\prod_{j, j\ne i} (1- \frac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_j})}\cdot \frac{\prod_{j} (1+ \frac{\alpha_i+1}{\alpha_j})}{\prod_{j} (1+ \frac{\alpha+1}{\alpha_j})}\cdot x^{\alpha_i}$$

Forecasting the case $\alpha_n = n^2$, let's consider the function
$$\phi(t) = \prod_j (1- \frac{t}{\alpha_j})$$

We have the projector formula

$$\sum_i \frac{\phi(\alpha)}{(1-\frac{\alpha}{\alpha_i}) \cdot (- \alpha_i \cdot \phi'(\alpha_i))} \cdot \frac{\phi(-(\alpha_i + 1))}{\phi(-(\alpha+1))} \cdot x^{\alpha_i}$$

Consider now the case $\alpha_k = k^2$. Then we get

$$\phi(t) = \prod_{k\ge 1} (1- \frac{t}{k^2}) = \frac{\sin \pi \sqrt{t}}{\pi \sqrt{t}}$$

while
$$\phi(-t) = \frac{\sinh \pi \sqrt{t}}{\pi \sqrt{t}}$$

One checks that at every $\alpha_k = k^2$ we have $ -k^2 \phi'(k^2) = \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2}$.

Now one puts all of it together. We get an analytic function.  More details later.

$\bf{Added:}$ The projector formula can also be written as

$$\sum_i \frac{\phi(\alpha)/(\alpha - \alpha_i)}{\phi'(\alpha_i)} \cdot \frac{\phi( -( \alpha_i + 1))}{\phi(-(\alpha+1))} \cdot x^{\alpha_i}$$

Comment: (+1) Finding an orthogonal vector using Gram determinant is new to me and quite entertaining! I also implemented this using Mathematica 13, and indeed the resulting expression seems to converge to some nice-looking function.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee: Found it in a [book](https://www.amazon.com/Functions-Mathematical-Physics-Dover-Books/dp/0486652149) I think Gram must have know about it. Now, the products in the quotients of Grams  ( the infinite ones) are very nice if $\alpha_n = n^2$ ( $\sin x= \ldots$) Maybe the limit functions have a nice explicit form.

Comment: I computed the expression using the Cauchy determinant, and if my computation is correct, it is $$x^{\alpha} - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\prod_{j=k+1}^{n} \Bigl(1 - \frac{\alpha}{\alpha_j}\Bigr)\Big/\Bigl(1 - \frac{\alpha_k}{\alpha_j}\Bigr)}{\prod_{j=1}^{n} \Bigl(1 + \frac{\alpha+1}{\alpha_j}\Bigr)\Big/\Bigl(1 + \frac{\alpha_k+1}{\alpha_j}\Bigr)} x^{\alpha_k}. $$ Under the assumption that $\sum_i \frac{1}{\alpha_i}<\infty$, each coefficient should converge as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: This seems to me to be an interesting comment, not an answer though.

Comment: @A rural reader: It may be so -- the label HINT was added. Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to include some terms in the formula above; The correct formula is: $$ \frac{D}{G(x^{\alpha_i}:i=1,\ldots,n)} = x^{\alpha} - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\prod_{j\in[n]\setminus\{k\}}^{n} \Bigl(1 - \frac{\alpha}{\alpha_j}\Bigr)\Big/\Bigl(1 - \frac{\alpha_k}{\alpha_j}\Bigr)}{\prod_{j=1}^{n} \Bigl(1 + \frac{\alpha+1}{\alpha_j}\Bigr)\Big/\Bigl(1 + \frac{\alpha_k+1}{\alpha_j}\Bigr)} x^{\alpha_k}, $$ where $[n] = \{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee: It's worth considering the concrete $\alpha_j = j^2$ and then $n\to \infty$ with courage. The infinite products are basically some $\sin$'s, so it should be an interesting formula.

Answer (score 5):

The M-S theorem does not say what you say it says. (In a comment I pointed out that there is an important quantifier missing from your version - the current problem is maybe more serious...)

If $\sum_{n\in S}1/n<\infty$ the theorem says that $V=span\{x^n:n\in S\}$ is not dense. That implies that there is a non-zero real *measure* "orthogonal" to everything in $V$, but not a continuous function.

Comment: You are right, I was a bit careless in mentioning the MS theorem. On the other hand, the trick used by Sangchul Lee to produce a continuous solution should produce a continuous solution (at least on the open interval) in the general case too. If a measure $\mu$ is orthogonal to $V$ then $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}\mu(t)\,dt$ should be a continuous function orthogonal to $V$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I suppose one can convert an orthogonal measure to a continuous function somehow. But the $f$ in your comment need not be continuous.